# twilio webrtc mediastream contentHint for android and ios

Tags: twilio

I want to prioritise Frame Detail over Frame Rate.
There is a parameter named contentHint in video media stream for it, but it may not be able to set by twilio sdk

https://www.w3.org/TR/mst-content-hint/

detail

> The track should be treated as if video details are extra important.
> This is generally applicable to presentations or web pages with text content,
> painting or line art.
> This setting would normally optimize for detail in the resulting individual frames
> rather than smooth playback. Artefacts from quantization or downscaling
> that make small text or line art unintelligible should be avoided.

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-ios/issues/59

In this github issue, I found that isScreencast is for it.
however Network Bandwidth Profile should be the official way to achieve it.

But as far as I tried, network bandwidth profile cannot achieve "Frame Detail over Frame Rate". What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

the `contentHint` attribute is set on a `MediaStreamTrack` so you could set this in a Twilio Video application. For example:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];

videoTrack.contentHint = "detail";

const room = await Twilio.Video.connect(token, { tracks: [videoTrack, audioTrack] });
```

If you set the `contentHint` on the video track and then pass the tracks directly to the `connect` method, they will be used.

If you want to set this directly via the Twilio Video SDK, I would recommend [raising a ticket in the Video.js repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js).

Comment: I want to set it to Android sdk and iOS sdk

Comment: to raise issues for android and ios where shall i post?

Comment: You mentioned a web standard draft attribute for `MediaStreamTrack`, which is not available in iOS or Android as the tracks are handled differently on each platform. You are right that this is not a feature of the network bandwidth API. If you are looking to make a feature request, I would speak to your Twilio account executive.

Comment: my goal is not developing "contentHints" but achieving "Frame Detail over Frame Rate". if it can be achieved with a network bandwidth api, it is still ok.

Comment: thank you for your info, but the github link which you share is not available, maybe twilio private one. where shall i post?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. As you've seen, the network bandwidth API does not currently support that, it cares more about turning tracks on and off and providing more bandwidth to higher priority tracks, in the case of presentation mode, for example. There is a repo for [Twilio Video iOS](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-ios/) which you could raise issues on too, the Video team does look at that repo and may be able to answer your query or make other suggestions that would help.

Comment: Yup, managed to share a private repo link there, sorry! The [iOS repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-ios/) is public though. (I republished my comment to remove the private link btw.)

Comment: do you have link for android? now we are targeting only for android

Comment: No, that repo is private. Your original question and other comments asked about iOS as well. If you need this, then I recommend you speak to your Twilio account executive, and if you don't have a sales rep [get in contact with sales here](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales), and tell them that you need this feature.